# How to confirm my node is on the network?

Tags: bitcoin-core, network, nodes, full-node

I wanted to verify that my node is on the bitcoin network. For this I used the 'getnetworkinfo' command on my bitcoincore console and was able to optain my node's IP address. This is: 2001:0:9d38:6abd:18e2:3f37:8f79:532e
I then entered this address and port (8333) into https://bitnodes.earn.com and my node checked out.
However my node does not display, when I look at the map of live nodes at: https://bitnodes.earn.com/nodes/live-map/

Can someone tell me why my node is not appearing on the live map?

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone tell me why my node is not appearing on the live map?

It is likely due to the software that they are running and it does not necessarily see your node. You don't have to be on the map in order to be online. You don't have to be listed on any website in order to be online. That you are not on the map should not concern you as it does not matter. It's just a fancy graphic and does not actually mean much.

You can check if you are connected to the network by using the `getconnectioncount` or `getnetworkinfo` commands. Those will tell you how many connections to other nodes that you have, and if it is more than 0, then you are connected to the Bitcoin network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrew.
Is it possible to connect to another node of my choice? My friend runs a node and I would like to be connected to his node. His IP is: 119.23.55.31:8333

Looking forward to your response

Comment: You can use the `addnode` command to connect to a specific node.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
bitcoin-cli getconnectioncount
```

How many connections do you have? Are you sure your port 8333 is open?

Bitnodes API returns a DOWN status for your node.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json; indent=4" https://bitnodes.earn.com/api/v1/nodes/2001:0:9d38:6abd:18e2:3f37:8f79:532e-8333/

{
    "hostname": "",
    "address": "2001:0:9d38:6abd:18e2:3f37:8f79:532e",
    "status": "DOWN",
    "data": null,
    "bitcoin_address": "",
    "url": "",
    "verified": false,
    "mbps": null }
```